# pass props to a component outside render function

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, Tracks, that lists songs and the song artist. The artist name is a link that will take the view to the ArtistDetail component. Like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpuBJ.jpg

I want it to be so that when a user clicks on an artist name, they will be taken to the artist detail component that will display "The artist is {name of artist clicked}". But as you can see in the snippet above, the artist name does not show up. When i did some consoling in the artist detail component it said that the prop name is undefined

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SpotifyWebAPI from "spotify-web-api-js";
import { ArtistDetail } from "./ArtistDetail";
const spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebAPI();

export class Tracks extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentArtist: "lala"
    };
  }

  openArtist = name => {
    this.setState({
      currentArtist: name
    });
    const artist = <ArtistDetail name={currentArtist}/>
     //even with const artist = <ArtistDetail name="francis"/> it says undefined

    this.props.switchView("ADetail");//this function is in change of changing the view from component to component.

    return artist;// it does not seem to return the prop to the component
  };

  render() {
    const { currentArtist } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Link
                      onClick={() => {
                        this.openArtist(artists.name);
                      }}
                    >
                      {console.log("the current artist")}
                      {console.log(currentArtist)}
                      {artists.name}
                    </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tracks;
```

Here is ArtistDetail.js component

```
export const ArtistDetail = (props) => {
    console.log("the prop name")
    console.log(props.name);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> The artist is </h1>
            <h1>{props.name}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I just wanted a situation where on click, props will be passed to the component. Onclick, artist detail should get the name of the artist as a prop and then switchView will switch the component shown from tracks to Artist detail. switchView does its job. But the name does not seem to get to artistDetail. From what i have read it seems that you cant call a component outside of a render method. But i dont know how else to get the prop to artist detail without that openArtist method

I tried this inside tracks render method:

```
{currentArtist != "lala" ? (<ArtistDetail name="francis"/>) && (this.props.switchView("ADetail"))
```

and it still could not display francis

Answer (score 2):

React updates the DOM and its data based on what happens in `render`. It doesn't really care what your components do. It only cares what you render. Any components created outside of `render` never get placed into the tree it keeps track of.

So, how do you update the rendered components? By updating the data, causing a rerender.

React is designed to flow data downwards as it renders. A parent might update its child, but a child doesn't update a parent, or sibling, or anything other than itself and its children. This is what lets all the magic happen inside `render()`. Because `render` focuses on what goes on with a component and its children, it only needs to care about how its state and props impacts the downstream components, rather than worrying about upstream stuff.

That's fine for rendering, but what happens if a downstream component lets a user change something upstream?

That's where messaging comes in. While data flows downstream, messages flow upstream. The idea is that rendering is a top-down process, but interaction is a bottom-up process.

The key is that in both circumstances, flow goes up and down the branches of the tree. Data flows to children, messages flow to parents. If we try to send messages to aunts and cousins dozens of times removed, we quickly lose track of who's in charge of what. By messaging up in order to stream data down, we can always look up the tree to find our source of truth.

There's some different ways of messaging.

- **handler props** This is the most tightly coupled way of  accessing parent data. It involves creating a function in the parent component that updates its state, then passing that function as a prop to the child. The child calls it with the updated information and the parent updates its state. Updating the state tells React to rerender that parent (and therefore its children) with the new state. Controlled form inputs do this. It's not practical, though, for handling multiple levels of components or complex data structures.
- **`useReducer()`** React 16.8 introduced Hooks, which add a lot of functionality to functional components. `useReducer` is an especially useful hook for managing more complex state across multiple components, such as for form data. Rather than drilling a method down for every piece of state being managed, `useReducer` returns a `dispatch` method that can be called with different objects that impact state in different ways. `dispatch({type: 'foo', value:'bar'})` might change the 'foo' value in the state managed by this instance of `useReducer`, while `dispatch({type: 'increment'})` might update a counter in another member of that same state object. By passing `dispatch` down from child to child, you can use it to tell the state to change from whatever child needs that ability, and the ancestor component will get the message to update its state and rerender itself and its descendants.
- **Global state managers** Packages such as Redux and MobX do things similar to `useReducer`, but on a larger scale. They provide ways to create a global state at the top of your app, but instead of having to drill your dispatch function all the way to where you need it, they let you pick and choose which components get to send messages and receive new data. They also have large ecosystems of plugins to extend their functionality.

For what you're describing, I'd probably go with a global state manager. Looking at your GIF, it looks like you'll end up with a pretty large data set, and the global managers have ways to simplify what state you need to know about in a given component. Also, if your detail view lives in a completely different branch from your list view, it'll be a lot of drilling to get a message from deep in the list all the way up and to the side with functions or `useReducer`. Global managers circumvent that.

If you used Redux, for example, you'd have state that looks something like

```js
{
  currentArtist: null,
  currentView: 'tracks',
  artists: [
    {...artist1Data},
    {...artist2Data},
    ...
  ]
}
```

This state would be defined at the very top of your app, available to every component if needed.

You'd then have a function, called a *reducer,* that takes messages and updates the state according to what that message requires. Redux then takes your initial state and your reducer, and gives you access to the state and a dispatch method, similar to what `useReducer` does.

Rather than having to drill those down to a deeply nested component, for classes you can wrap that component in Redux's higher-order component, or for functional components you can access the state and dispatch via the `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` hooks.

So, with this state, instead of passing a `switchView` method in the props, the top-level component holding the roots of the different views would access the Redux state, check the `currentView` member, and show that view. When the Track component needs to switch to the artist detail view, it would get access to Redux's `dispatch` method and dispatch an *action* to Redux, perhaps like `dispatch({type: 'switchView', view: 'detail'})`. Your reducer recognizes the 'switchView' action type and updates that top-level global state's `currentView` member to 'detail'.

Since we had already hooked up that view switching component, it knows when the Redux state changes. It sees that the current view should now be 'detail', and it rerenders to show that instead of the 'tracks' view.

The missing piece is updating the artist. It's almost identical to updating the view. Before we update the view, we dispatch another action, such as `dispatch({type: 'setCurrentArtist', artist: name})`. This time, the reducer sees 'setCurrentArtist' and knows to set the `currentArtist` member to the value passed in `artist`. Instead of creating a new ArtistDetail component, however, we already have an existing ArtistDetail component inside the detail view. When we connect it to the Redux state, it can recognize when currentArtist has changed, and then it rerenders itself when that global state value changes.

That's the key with changing how React apps appear to the user. To update a presentation, we can't modify the existing components. Once a render occurs, it's sent off to the wild, never to be seen again. Instead, we trigger rerenders, by updating the props and state  in the current component, or by messaging for data changes in ancestor components. Basically, every time we want a branch to look different, we rerender the entire branch by changing the data.

This sounds incredibly inefficient, but React was designed to do this very quickly. If it starts feeling laggy, it offers you ways to cache some of this, but typically that happens if the components themselves are complex to render, not because of the raw number of components.

Comment: so in the case of handle props, i will make a fucntion in tracks then pass that function to artist detail as a prop. When you say the child will call it with updated info, what do you mean? Is the updated info coming from the child or the parent?

Comment: Oh! The key is that the function isn't created *inside* Tracks. It needs to be handed down from whatever ancestor contains both Tracks and the original ArtistDetail. Called in Tracks, but defined in Dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I missed the comment about francois. Looking further, here's something...

ArtistDetail is being created in an event handler. It's being returned to onClick, and it disappears, because event handlers aren't expected to return anything.

If you want to change a particular element, you have to change its props in its existing location, or replace it in its parent. I strongly recommend changing props versus creating a new one, because creating a new  component gets expensive at scale.

If the data is in a completely different location in the tree, consider managing state using useReducer or a global state manager, and dispatching updates that flow down from the top. That's React's core principle: data flows down.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean. Right now artist detail is not even getting "francis" as a prop. currentArtist is not currently supposed to do anything in the render function? Its updated in the openArtist function. Why does currentArtist in render need to be tied the object and what object is that. Thank you

Comment: Haha yeah, I saw that afterwards. Sorry! I rewrote when I looked further.

Comment: yeah thats what i am trying to do, change the prop.name in artistdetail as it is being updated with the onclick function in tracks. I dont understand. Ok can you explain why it is not recognizing francis? Maybe i can understand. And sorry where am i creating a new prop. thank you

Comment: Okay, so what you're doing herenis creating a new ArtistDetail component... but you're not putting it into your app. It's being created, then immediately discarded. I'm guessing your other view has a default ArtistDetail component in it? That's what you're seeing,  not this new component. In order for this update to be visible, you have to either embed the new instance in your other view, or update the instance already in that view. I'll add a new answer to explain the idea behind how React expects updates to occur.

Comment: ok i tried this:{currentArtist != "lala" ? (<ArtistDetail name="francis"/>) && (this.props.switchView("ADetail")) : null} inside the tracks render method and it still could not even display francis

Comment: Well... that would create the new ArtistDetail, but it would stick it inside the cell with the link in it, because it's part of render. Except for two things: 1) the && means the second term  -- whatever is returned by switchView() -- is output instead. I'm assuming its return is undefined, so nothing would be output. The other thing is, even if you created it in the link table cell,  you wouldn't see it, because you switched views away from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so looking at your Dashboard component, it appears like `switchView` is coming from the component above Dashboard. When it's called, I'm assuming it updates the state on that parent component. Updating state on a component tells React to re-call that component's `render` method, rerendering itself and its children.

The thing is that Dashboard renders the appropriate child, but without populating any props for them. I'm guessing Home and Tracks have default presentations that don't need props, but ArtistDetail doesn't have anything available to it.

By the time you get into Tracks, you're already beyond the reach of Dashboard, so Dashboard doesn't know what Tracks is doing. Creating a new ArtistDetail under Tracks won't help. You need to make the current artist available to Dashboard, so that it can plug the artist into the ArtistDetail it can see.

One way to do this is to do the same kind of thing you do to update the current view -- create a function to update a `currentArtist` state in Dashboard. Pass that state into Dashboard's ArtistDetail component. Pass the function down to your link, and send the new current artist through that function. Sending the new artist updates Dashboard's state, and it rerenders with the new `currentArtist` being passed to ArtistDetail.

```
export const Dashboard = ({ currentView, switchView}) => {

  // Get the current artist from state and a setter to update the state.
  // We set the state to "" as an initial value.
  const [currentArtist, setCurrentArtist] = useState("");

  return (
    <div >
      {currentView == "Home" && <Home/>}
      {currentView == "Tracks" && <Tracks switchView={switchView} currentView={currentView} setCurrentArtist={setCurrentArtist}/>} // make "setCurrentArtist" available to Tracks
      {currentView == "SearchE" && <SearchE/>}
      {currentView == "Popular" && <Popular/>}
      {currentView == "ADetail" && <ArtistDetail name={currentArtist} />}//when i do switchView("ADetail") in tracks, it switches to the artist view
    </div>
  );
};
```

As long as the link in Tracks calls `this.props.setCurrentArtist` before calling `this.props.switchViews`, the currentArtist state will be populated and ready for the switch.

This is an example of the handler props pattern I described below.

1. The ancestor passes down a function.
2. The descendant passes the message up via the function.
3. The state is changed in the ancestor.
4. React sees that the ancestor's state changed, and calls the ancestor's `render` function.
5. The ancestor renders itself and its descendants with the updated data.

Hopefully this helps give a feel for how messages update ancestor data in order to update children.

Of course, now you've got two functions you're passing around your app. Imagine how it feels when you have a lot more functionality scattered about! Function props work for a few bits of functionality, but at some point one of the other methods described in my other answer might be easier to manage.

Comment: Oh bless you bless you bless you. It worked. I really did not want to use Redux yet. I needed to get into the head space for that and i was not there yet. I will update the app with redux later on. Thank you SO much for being patient and actually coming back to look through my ramblings. I wish i could send you a gift basket. Thank you for your kindness and i hope people behave the same way to you and much more.